# Controlling the final size of a Sprite object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm rendering a xps file using flash (no MX or Spark), and I'm running into a sort of 'contradiction' that I'm unable to solve. [Note, that I'm trying to work only in core flash (e.g. Sprite, Shape, etc.), I've already solved (sort of) this issue using Spark.]

The pages of the xps file specify an explicit size. However, the content described (especially paths) in the xps file can sometimes extend outside of this area.

The problem is, I want the parent Sprite to have the size specified by the xps file, for example so scroll bars match the page size (not the sprite size), but in some cases the Sprite is much larger than this.

I've tried recursively going down and scaling everything UP, and then at the end scaling the parent container DOWN. Unfortunately, this causes translation problems with paths, and I assume it can also cause problems with bitmaps, etc.

Without using MX or Spark, is there anything I can do to control the size of the parent Sprite, other than scaling all the children independently?

cheers!

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly...?
a) You want your sprite to have dimensions of some minimum width and height.
b) you need the sprite to be exactly widht x height dimensions
and/or
c) you need it to scale down as needed, but not up as needed?
The question was a bit unclear to me.

Comment: You have to parse the file and get the data yourself.

Comment: You can always override set/get width and set/get height functions . Maybe it will help ?

Comment: to answer mfa, my question is 'b'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be misreading what you're looking for, but you might find the solution by using the scrollRect property of your display object containers. If objects inside the container extend beyond the boundaries, they'll be clipped. You can still get to them by changing the x and y positions of the scrollRect. [(link)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#scrollRect)

Comment: Looks like scrollRect is the way to go. Thanks James.